# Why do people say "SOFR vs OIS discounting" when OIS depends on a rate that could be SOFR?

Tags: sofr, ois, ois-discounting

As I understand it, OIS is not a published rate. SOFR is a published rate.

Based on this published rate, OIS swaps are constructed. The fixed rate on these swaps that makes both legs worth the same is what's called an "OIS" rate.

So we can construct this OIS rate from SOFR rates, or from Libor, or whatever.

So why do people use phrases like "going from OIS discounting to SOFR discounting" when we're STILL OIS discounting --- we're just using a SOFR published rate instead of libor. So isn't a phrase like that downright wrong?

An example https://www.risk.net/investing/derivatives/7445616/sofr-discounting-analysing-the-market-impactwhere this phrase is used:

Comment: You are right.  For the longest time in the US, OIS swaps were based on Fed Funds.  Over time people started assuming OIS always meant Fed Funds, but as you point out, OIS is a style of swap, not a published rate.